# Grouping date periods (by number of days) but exclude the weekends?

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have a table with start and end dates in. My goal is to have a table that has grouped these dates into how many days the period spans. I thought I had the solution with a simple SQL statement (MS SQL Server 2005) but I want to exclude weekends.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(D, StartDate, EndDate)+1 AS Days,
 COUNT(ID) as Count 
FROM myDateTable
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(D, StartDate, EndDate)
```

This gives a record set of:

```
Days Count
1    4
2    2
4    1
7    2
```

Is this possible to exclude the weekends in the SQL statement and if not can it be done using ASP and a array perhaps?

Comment: Can you add tables to your data source?  I can see a way to do it with special look up tables inside of SQL Server.  Also, can see a way to do it inside of ASP using a loop.  Which way would you prefer?

Comment: Yes I can add tables to my data source but I think I would prefer an ASP solution to adding tables.

Comment: Which version of Sql Server are you using?

Comment: The problem you're going to run into with an ASP solution is you're going to have to pull your entire dataset into your ASP page.  IE, you lose the grouping functions of SQL Server.

Comment: Ok, what would be the solution using just SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Well then, using Sql Server 2005, you can try something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        StartDate DATETIME,
        EndDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @Table (ID,StartDate,EndDate) SELECT 1, '25 Jan 2009', '31 Jan 2009'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,StartDate,EndDate) SELECT 2, '01 Jan 2009', '07 Jan 2009'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,StartDate,EndDate) SELECT 3, '01 Jan 2009', '14 Jan 2009'

DECLARE @MinDate    DATETIME,
        @MaxDate DATETIME

SELECT  @MinDate = MIN(StartDate) ,
        @MaxDate = MAX(EndDate) 
FROM    @Table
--Create a temp result set between the Min and Max dates, with all dates, and their weekday names
;WITH DayValues AS(
        SELECT  @MinDate DateVal,
                DATENAME(dw, @MinDate) DateValName
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  DateVal + 1,
                DATENAME(dw, DateVal + 1) DateValName
        FROM    DayValues
        WHERE   DateVal + 1 <= @MaxDate
),
--select the count of days for each StartDate and EndDate pair, excluding Saturdays and Sundays
DateCounts AS(
        SELECT  ID,
                (
                    SELECT  COUNT(1) 
                    FROM    DayValues 
                    WHERE   DateVal BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate 
                    AND     DateValName NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
                ) DateCount
        FROM    @Table
)
--Now group and count
SELECT  DateCount,
        COUNT(ID) TotalCount
FROM    DateCounts
GROUP BY DateCount
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Output

```
DateCount   TotalCount
----------- -----------
5           2
10          1
```

**EDIT: Brief Explenation**

You need to determine the number of days between (and including) 2 dates, that are not weekends.

So using a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx), I create a temporary result set of dates ebwteen the Min and Max dates, and their Weekday Name (eg Monday, Tuesday... Sunday).

Then, for each of your date pairs, I count the number of entries that does not correspond to Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: Hi astander, any chance you could explain what is going on here? I'm not a SQL server guru by any stretch of the imagination!

Comment: I gave a breif explenation. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ASP function that counts days weekdays between two dates.

```
<%
    Dim StartDate, EndDate

    StartDate = CDate("1/1/2010")
    EndDate = CDate("2/1/2010")

    Response.Write(WeekDayCount(StartDate, EndDate))


    Function WeekDayCount(StartDate, EndDate)
        dim tempDate, dayCount

        tempDate = StartDate
        dayCount = 0

        'Step forward one day, counting non-week days 
        While tempDate <> EndDate 
            'The 1 and 7 might need to be tweaked depending on the locale of your
            'server.  1 = Sunday, 7 = Saturday
            If DatePart("w", tempDate) <> 1 And DatePart("w", tempDate) <> 7 Then
                dayCount = dayCount + 1
            End If

            tempDate = DateAdd("d", 1, tempDate)
        Wend

          WeekDayCount = dayCount
    End Function
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at @@DATEFIRST,

and look a this;

SELECT DATEPART(DW,GETDATE()).

You should be able to run a query WHERE the 'DW' is not equal to the weekend numbers.